# Reassign unallocated space with gparted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

some months ago I decided to create a new partition on my 500GB drive to run Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows 10. I was pretty sure that 97GB (100000 MB) would be more than enough for what I was trying to do, but now I am running out of disk space (I need roughly at least 60 more GB). Fortunately my Windows 10 partition (/dev/sda4) had a lot of empty space to free, so I shrank that partition and I obtained a 97GB of unallocated space. The problem is: how do I add that space to my current root partition (/dev/sda6) without breaking anything?

[image: A screenshot of my current partitions]

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Little key icons show partitions are mounted. You cannot change mounted partitions, so use live installer. Actually with gpt I have found I can create a new partition in unallocated space as long as I do not try to modify mounted partitions.  You then could create /home or /data partition and use that as an alternative.

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 1):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/sda6 partition all the way left
- **resize** /dev/sda6 right side all the way right
- click the Apply icon